# Best way to store/model game data on a Django website?

Tags: javascript, django, pubnub

Please allow me to set up the environment for my question:

- On my website, users register for an account and then go to the game page
- Once 5 players load in to the game page, a new game starts. The game works as follows:

  - Players guess numbers until they find the "magic number", which is a random number from 1-100
  - Once 3 players have guessed the magic number correctly, the other 2 are declared the losers and kicked from the page

**My question is as follows**: *what is the best way to store individual game information?* In order for the game to operate correctly, the website needs to somehow hold information on the game; specifically, a counter that increments every time a player guesses the magic number correctly.

Points of consideration:

- I would like to make it so multiple games could be going on at once (website.com/game could have multiple gaming sessions going on at once on it), so the solution should not inhibit that.
- I am running my website with Django, along with HTML/CSS/JavaScript
- This is (probably obviously) a simplified version of the game I am implementing online. In reality, the solution would be able to hold multiple dynamic variables/information on the game.

Comment: Your question is probably going to get downvoted because this is too open-ended, but here's my quick suggestion: POST the guesses to your own server to check a database for the current count. If < 3 then increment. When it reaches 3, publish a message to a channel (using PubNub) to update all the players and announce their status: winners or losers. The DB updates to the counter will need to done so that the read/update of the counter is locked to prevent other updates (first in wins). You may have to use a message queue to control this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing game information will likely be the straightforward part of this task. Consider how you will construct your models. I would have a `Game`, `PlayerInGame`, and `User` model (which I assume you already have).

This looks like an opportunity to use a through model (`PlayerInGame`), as you will need to have some way of denoting players in the game as winners vs losers.

```
class Game(models.Model):
     winning_magic_number = models.IntegerField()
     players = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='PlayerInGame',
        through_fields=('game', 'user'),
    )

class PlayerInGame(models.Model):
      WINNER = 'Winner'
      LOSER = 'Loser'
      UKNOWN = 'Unknown'
      PLAYER_TYPE_CHOICES = [
             (WINNER, 'Winner'),
             (LOSER, 'Loser'),
             (UKNOWN, 'Unknown')
         ]

     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     game = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     type = models.CharField(choices=PLAYER_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Every time a user joins a game, you should create an instance of a `PlayerInGame` model with the joining user and the game they have joined. They could start off as `Unknown`, with their status changing as the game progresses.

The real time aspect of this application - needing to have players guess numbers and have the models respond accordingly - may be the more challenging portion. You will need a Websocket. See Django Channels for how to create real-time features with Django + websockets. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

As Craig noted, this is an open-ended question and the real-time portion of this is too long to explain here; but hopefully, these ideas have gotten you started!